# output javascript template to html page inside a row div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, underscore.js-templating

I have json api which is a list of books with their properties: title, author, etc.. I need to output the data formatted to html. I'm using es6 backtics for this and javascript templating. But the problem I'm encountering is that the output is not one iterationg to html page, but every two iteration. every single object from json goes into an html card. But my page requires two cards per row. so I need to insert an opening row div every two iteration and an closing row div every two iteration, so that in between the opening row and closing div I have the two cards. I first thought to put my template in a variable, but that didn't work. Second I put it in a function with return statement. this time work, but I can properly insert the row tags... could someone suggest proper easier way to do this? thanks
here's the index.html page. the two cards are in one row. I don't know before hand how many card I will need. the output will be posted to list-ouput id.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Book Finder</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="title" class="center">
        <h1 class="text-center mt-5">Book Finder</h1>
        <div class="row">
          <div id="input" class="input-group mx-auto col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-12">
            <input id="search-box" type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Search Books!...">
            <button id="search" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="">Search</button>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="book-list" >
        <h2 class="text-center">Search Result</h2>
        <div id="list-output" class="">
          <div class="row">
            <!-- card  -->
            <div class="col-lg-6">
              <div class="card" style="">
                <div class="row no-gutters">
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img src="" class="card-img" alt="...">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Book Title</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">Author</p>
                      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Publisher: </small></p>
                      <a href="${bookLink}" class="btn btn-secondary">More Info</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- card  -->
            <div class="col-lg-6">
              <div class="card" style="">
                <div class="row no-gutters">
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img src="" class="card-img" alt="...">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h5 class="card-title">Book Title</h5>
                      <p class="card-text">Author</p>
                      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Publisher: </small></p>
                      <a href="${bookLink}" class="btn btn-secondary">More Info</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    <!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```html
$(document).ready(function() {
      var item, tile, author, publisher, bookLink, bookImg;
      var outputList = document.getElementById("list-output");
    
      //listener for search button
      $("#search").click(function() {
         $("#title").animate({'margin-top': '5px'}, 1000);
         // $(".book-list").css("visibility", "visible");
         var searchData = $("#search-box").val();
         if(searchData === "") {
           // dsiplayErr();
         } else {
           console.log(searchData);
           $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q="+searchData, function(response) {
              for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {
                item = response.items[i];
                title = item.volumeInfo.title;
                author = item.volumeInfo.authors;
                publisher = item.volumeInfo.publisher;
                bookLink = item.selfLink;
                bookImg = item.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail;
                // in production code, item.text should have the HTML entities escaped.
    
                if( (i+2) % 2 != 0) {
                  console.log("odd")
                  outputList.innerHTML += `<div class="row">`;
                }
                outputList.innerHTML += formatOutput(title, author, bookLink, bookImg);
                if((i+2) % 2 == 0) {
                  console.log("even")
                  outputList.innerHTML += `</div>`;
                }
                console.log(outputList.innerHTML);
              }
            });
          }
       });
    
    });
    
    
    
    function formatOutput(title, author, publisher, bookLink, bookImg) {
      // console.log(title + ""+ author +" "+ publisher +" "+ bookLink+" "+ bookImg)
      var htmlCard1 = `<div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="card" style="">
          <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <img src="${bookImg}" class="card-img" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">${title}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Author: ${author}</p>
                <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Publisher: ${publisher}</small></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>`
      return htmlCard1;
    }
```

Comment: Why don't try to work with the DOM instead of strings? You have some sort of limitations on it or what?

Comment: @ 0xc14m1z do you have time to provide an example.. like DOM traversal.. anything? the html code is not fixed on the page.. I don't know how many times I will be outputting code to html

Comment: Can you provide in your answer a sample of the data you get back from the server?

Comment: @0xc14m1z set `searchData` to something like `john` and the code above will return data.

Comment: @0xc14m1z check the url embedded in the code in section $.get()

Comment: @hungrystart when I investigate further string "john" is not in my code.. so don't know how is that going to work

Comment: @miatech, I was informing @0xc14m1z on how to get some example data from the server. Running `var searchData = 'john'; $.get( "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q="+searchData )` returns a response with 10 items.

Comment: May be you can provide sample of how it should look at the end, not clear otherwise.. You don’t have to do it all on the fly, instead saving to a variable then loop.. Instead of splitting div between 2 iterations, better to create in first it and append in second..

Answer (score 1):

I removed few lines which i thought were unnecessary but you can add them back if you want. Following code should be working as you expected

```
       $(document).ready(function () {
            var item, tile, author, publisher, bookLink, bookImg;
            var outputList = $("#list-output");

            //listener for search button
            $("#search").click(function () {
                var searchData = $("#search-box").val();
                if (searchData === "") {
                    // dsiplayErr();
                } else {
                    console.log(searchData);
                    $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=" + searchData, function (response) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {
                            item = response.items[i];
                            title = item.volumeInfo.title;
                            author = item.volumeInfo.authors;
                            publisher = item.volumeInfo.publisher;
                            bookLink = item.selfLink;
                            bookImg = item.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail;
                            // in production code, item.text should have the HTML entities escaped.
                            var html;
                            if ((response.items.length % 2 != 0) && (i == response.items.length - 1)) {
                                html = "";
                                html += "<div class='row'>";
                                html += formatOutput(title, author, publisher, bookLink, bookImg);
                                html += "</div>";
                                outputList.append(html);
                            }
                            else {
                                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                                    html = "";
                                    html += "<div class='row'>";
                                }

                                html += formatOutput(title, author, publisher, bookLink, bookImg);

                                if (i % 2 != 0) {
                                    html += "</div>";
                                    outputList.append(html);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

        });



        function formatOutput(title, author, publisher, bookLink, bookImg) {
            // console.log(title + ""+ author +" "+ publisher +" "+ bookLink+" "+ bookImg)
                var htmlCard1 = `<div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="card" style="">
                  <div class="row no-gutters">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <img src="${bookImg}" class="card-img" alt="...">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">${title}</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Author: ${author}</p>
                        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Publisher: ${publisher}</small></p>
                        <a href="${bookLink}" class="btn btn-secondary">More Info</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>`
            return htmlCard1;
        }
```